# Mylyn opening unwanted files in editors from task context

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

I'm using Mylyn 3.12 for the first time with Eclipse Kepler. I am using subversive to manage SVN connection for team.

I doing web development, so no Java projects here. I'm having the craziest situation where Mylyn is always adding three files to every task I create after I deactivate and then reactivate the task. It's almost as though there is a hidden editor with these files open. I have no idea where they might be coming from. Why on earth it chooses these three files is beyond me. If I delete one of the files, it still tries to add the file to the context, but the editor opens with file does not exist. When I "clear all" from the task context, stop the task, and reactivate, the files still appear! I even clear the invisible section as well.

Does anyone have any idea what might be linking these files to the context?

Also, I'm using the ColdFusion builder plugin, so I don't know if was related to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, on a hunch while dissecting this issue, I decided to go through the "Window->Navigation->Switch to Editor" Each of my three files had it's own editor listed here! However, I found no way to actually get to these editors. So, whenever a task was created, it would simply copy open files from these hidden editors. So, I had two copies of each file open. I have no idea what is going on with my "shared area."

Again, the only way I could get to the hidden editors was the Window menu item, so it beats me if this is a bug or a feature. It almost seems like it was split editor view gone terribly wrong.